# Can the Parse Server master key be randomized for each instance?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Given a group of Parse Server instances behind a load balancer.

For security purposes I want to randomize the Parse Server master key on each Parse Server launch. This mitigates the risk in case a master key is compromised, because each generated master key would become invalidated regularly and only live for a short period of time.

In this scenario the instances of Parse Server are running simultaneously, isolated from each other, using different master keys, but serving the same app and sharing the same underlying database.

I don't see an issue here, but are there any potential side effects?

Comment: Maybe it could be a problem in parse-dashboard side or if you use an admin panel for your app with master-key.

Comment: Thanks, parse dashboard is good point, that would definitely create a problem because the master key is set in the dashboard. I wonder if there is a way to circumvent that without running the dashboard on the same instance as the server but I guess not.